# How could i store values from the loop and compare it later

Tags: java

How could i store values from the loop and compare it later.

As per the below program.. I have a string value "developer java". I want to split this as "developer" and "java". After split i want to search whether the developer word is available in the Str1, Str2, Str3 and then again i want to search the word "java" with all the three Str's and compare the first iteration result and second iteration result and display the common Str from both the iterations..

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.List;

public class DelJava {
public static void main(String [] args){

    DelJava d = new DelJava();
    d.splitFunction();

}

public void splitFunction(){
    String keyword= "developer java";
    String[] splitKeywords=keyword.split("\\s");

    for(String splitKeyword:splitKeywords){
            String Str1 = "I am a java developer";
            String Str2 = "I am a developer";
            String Str3 = "I am learning java"; 
            String Str4 = "I am a programmer";
            //System.out.println(splitKeyword); 
            System.out.println("=== Loop Starts ===");  
            List<String> listStrings = new ArrayList<String>();

            if (!Str1.contains(splitKeyword))
                //System.out.println("Keyword "+splitKeyword+" Not available in Str1 - "+Str1);
                listStrings.add(Str1);

            if (!Str2.contains(splitKeyword))
                //System.out.println("Keyword "+splitKeyword+" Not available in Str2 - "+Str2);
                listStrings.add(Str2);

            if (!Str3.contains(splitKeyword))
                //System.out.println("Keyword "+splitKeyword+" Not available in Str3 - "+Str3);
                listStrings.add(Str3);

            if (!Str4.contains(splitKeyword))
                //System.out.println("Keyword "+splitKeyword+" Not available in Str3 - "+Str3);
                listStrings.add(Str4);

            System.out.println(listStrings);

            System.out.println("=== Loop Ends ===");    

    } 
}
```

}

Comment: use an array outside your for loop or have nest for loop

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare 
List listStrings = new ArrayList();
out side of for loop.
  List listStrings = new ArrayList();
for(String splitKeyword:splitKeywords){

Comment: Hi Lakhan Singh, I have tried that... Getting output like this..
[I am learning java, I am a programmer, I am a developer, I am a programmer]
Actually, i need to display just the duplicated ones.. i.e., I am a programmer..  could u pls help me with this..